# Why do we get "Path not found" error while accessing vb code from classic asp page?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Could you please give your suggestions to the below problem:

I am working on a old project which was developed using traditional ASP and VB6.0. 
I have registered the dll in component services. After creating the object in first line (in the code snippet below), when trying to call Login() method, it is giving the "Path not found" warning/error and I am not able to continue executing it further. 
Thanks in advance for your consideration and help...also please let me know if you need more information...

```
SET objSecurity = Server.CreateObject(  Application("APP_CLASS") & "Security" )
SET ox = new XMLTool
userID = uCase(userID)
dataXML = ""
IF objSecurity.Login( sessXML, userID, pwd, datXML ) Then
   ox.LoadXML dataXML 
   ..........
   ..........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Path not found" is usually an IO exception.  Does the objSecurity.Login() method read or write any data to a file or directory that does not exist?  What is happening inside the objSecurity.Login() method?

Alternately, is there another "benign" method of the objSecurity object that you can call to verify that the object lives?  Something like:

```
Dim sTest As String = objSecurity.Version()
```

or

```
Dim sTest As String = objSecurity.Name()
```

or even

```
Dim bExists As Boolean = (objSecurity IsNot Nothing)
```

I know that .ToString() didn't exist in VB6, but that's the idea.

Let's narrow down the problem to either objSecurity object itself, or something inside the .Login() method.

Comment: GOT IT. I debugged the code and found that I copied the dll into wrong folder and registered that dll in Component Services. Some other methods(those that were intern called by Login() method) were using App.Path which caused the problem. Thank you so much for your quick help.